# How to print code generated by some function in php?

Tags: php, drupal

I have a code in my CMS that prints content:`<?php print $content ?>`
I would like to output the actual php and html code behind `$content`, ideally in the browser. What I mean here is not the result in the browser, but the actual code behind it.Is it possible at all?

EDIT: Just to explain further: I need to print the source code of $content. Basically this variable produce some html and php content. I would like to see the code it produces, change it and replace $content with my custom code. Ideally the source code should be printed in the browser, is there anny php function that does it?

Comment: You could perhaps get the contents of the file the function is defined in, and then print the relevant parts.

Comment: You mean a [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing))?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean. Maybe you can give some example code and the output you expect?

Comment: Is this for debugging by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

First off install the [Devel Module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), it has a wonderful function called `dpm()` which will print the contents of any variable to the Drupal messages area.

Then you need to go into your theme's `template.php` file and implement `hook_preprocess_page()`:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  dpm($vars['content']);
}
```

That will print out the `$content` array before it's rendered into a string. In the same preprocess function you can also change `$vars['content']` as you see fit, and the changes will be reflected in `$content` in `page.tpl.php`.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'the code'? I think what you want to do is not possible, unless you make some kind of quine it's not possible to output the actual php code of a php file when you run it.

If `$content` is something like:

```
$content = 3 + 4 + 5;
```

`echo $content;` will output `12` yes? But I'm taking it you want to output `3 + 4 + 5` or something along those lines. The thing is, PHP (although it doesn't *feel* like it) is compiled. In this trivial example, `3 + 4 + 5` is stored exactly nowhere in your compiled program, it is stored as `12` (since it's static). More complex lines of code will be stored as pointers, values etc., all in nicely obfuscated machine code. Getting back to the `3 + 4 + 5` requires reading the input file and outputting the relevant line, which is difficult (think about what happens if you add or remove some lines, or how your running program knows where in the source file it is, or even if it's in the right source file).

tl;dr: this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to see html source for $content, you should simply use htmlspecialchars  :

```
echo htmlspecialchars($content);
```

http://php.net/htmlspecialchars
or http://php.net/htmlentities

Comment: I can also chceck page source code in the browser, but that's not what I need.